# Solving recurrence using sympy

Tags: sympy, recurrence

I was trying to solve recurrence relation of fibonacci series using sympy. I got an answer which is different from that of the text book. Dont know where I got it wrong.

My sympy code

```
from sympy import *
f=Function('f')
var('y')
var('n',integer=True)
f=y(n)-y(n-1)+(n-2)
rsolve(f,y(n))
```

And output is

> C0 + (-n + 1)*(n/2 - 1)

Comment: The output is correct for the recurrence equation `f` (`=0`) you provide. Are you sure this is the correct form of `f`? I believe the recurrence relation of fibonacci series is `f = y(n) - y(n-1) - y(n-2)` (`=0`)

Comment: In addition to what @Stelios mentioned, rsolve allows for initial conditions. Two are typically given for the fibonacci.

Comment: @Stelios How to give initial conditions?

Comment: @user567879 You provide a dictionary as initial conditions. See the [rsolve](http://docs.sympy.org/dev/modules/solvers/solvers.html#module-sympy.solvers.recurr) documentation

Comment: @Stelios Gave as `print rsolve(f,y(n),{y(0):1,y(1):1})` and getting None are result.

Answer (score 11):

Here's a complete code for solving the Fibonacci recursion. Please note carefully the correct use of `Function` and `symbols`.

```
from sympy import *
y = Function('y')
n = symbols('n',integer=True)
f = y(n)-y(n-1)-y(n-2)
rsolve(f,y(n),{y(0):0, y(1):1})
```

> `sqrt(5)*(1/2 + sqrt(5)/2)**n/5 - sqrt(5)*(-sqrt(5)/2 + 1/2)**n/5`

Comment: Text gave the answer as http://imgur.com/a/YUi1t Also y(0) is 1 for fabanocci (I gave like that).